# mvn in bash works, but IntelliJ yields "error: release version 17 not supported"

Tags: java, bash, maven, intellij-idea, makefile

I'm not super experienced with Maven, and certainly not with makefiles.

I have a makefile with a step like so:

```
do-build:
    mvn clean install -DskipTests -Dspotbugs.skip=true -Dpmd.skip=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true
```

Within a bash shell I can run both the `make do-build` command and the specified Maven command directly. This works just fine.

However, viewing the makefile within IntelliJ, it shows a green ">" icon in the gutter next to `do-build`, but clicking that icon gives me an error `Fatal error compiling: error: release version 17 not supported` which I am unable to resolve. Why??

I have ensured that:

- `update-alternatives --config java` is correctly set to corretto-17.
- `which java` reports the correct Java binary.
- `$JAVA_HOME` points to this binary.
- IntelliJ Settings > Java Compiler > Project bytecode version: is set to 17.
- IntelliJ Settings > Maven > JDK for importer: is set to 17.
- IntelliJ Project Structure > Project: SDK & Language level: are both set to 17.
- IntelliJ Project Structure > Modules: Language level: is set to 17.
- the `component` element in `.idea/misc.xml` lists JDK 17.
- My `pom.xml` file lists:

  - ```
    properties > java.version: 17
    ```
  - ```
    properties > maven.compiler.source: ${java.version}
    ```
  - ```
    properties > maven.compiler.target: ${java.version}
    ```
  - ```
    build > plugins > plugin > artifactId maven-compiler-plugin > configuration > source: ${java.version}
    ```
  - ```
    build > plugins > plugin > artifactId maven-compiler-plugin > configuration > target: ${java.version}
    ```
- "Choose Boot Runtime for the IDE" is set to 17.
- I have tried invalidating IntelliJ cache etc.

In short, I have run out of things to check. There must be something though...?

FWIW, this is a brand new installation of Ubuntu MATE 22.04.

Comment: The JVM running maven is too Old. Does it work from the command line.

Comment: `mvn -X | grep  '^Java version'` shows what?

Comment: @g00se, I get `Java version: 17.0.9, vendor: Amazon.com Inc., runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-amazon-corretto` - both when I run it in the terminal, and if I create a new `foo` task in the makefile and run `make foo`. -- BUT if I then click "run" on that makefile task (from within IntelliJ, that is), I get `Java version: 11.0.21, vendor: Ubuntu, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64` instead!

Comment: Now I'm contemplating simply removing openjdk-11, although I am a mite worried that would affect (break) other parts of my system.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't use IntelliJ but it looks to me like the setting is coming from there

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have checked _everything_ in IntelliJ, I've no idea where it grabs that old JDK from. To the bin it goes!

Comment: I'm assuming you are executing the script via IDEA's Terminal? IDEA might be using a deferent shell/environment compared to the shell you start explicitly from the OS. Try starting IDEA from OS' shell with "idea" command and check if your script executes successfully. See also: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-tools-terminal.html

Comment: @LéaGris thank you for your thoughtful comment. I'm using what is mandated by my employer.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the problem is that [IntelliJ IDEA uses wrong $JAVA_HOME when running things inside it, and I can't change it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38521283/intellij-idea-uses-wrong-java-home-when-running-things-inside-it-and-i-cant-c) which is a different class of problem (one that has many, many questions here).

In the end, I put `echo $JAVA_HOME` into my makefile to see what it pointed to *when running through the IDE*, and then I made a symlink for that path pointing to my actual JDK. **This is not a fix** for the root issue, but a practical work-around.